# Combining/joining two queries with a different where clause

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query which works. It includes the total amount of transactions with all statuses from billing.transaction table. I need to add another (4th) column with amount of transactions with a specific status (for example 'active') in order to calculate the  ratio of total amount of transactions with 'active'status over t_amount for each city. Will be grateful for your support.

Thank you in advance.

```
`select left(t.reference_id,5) as city_code,
   case when left(t.reference_id,5) = 'DE-01' then 'city1'
        when left(t.reference_id,5) = 'DE-02' then 'city2'
        when left(t.reference_id,5) = 'DE-03' then 'city3'
        when left(t.reference_id,5) = 'DE-04' then 'city4'
        when left(t.reference_id,5) = 'DE-05' then 'city5'
        when left(t.reference_id,5) = 'DE-09' then 'city6'
        when left(t.reference_id,5) = 'DE-11' then 'city7'
        else 'city8'
        end as city,
   sum(e.amount) as t_amount
from billing.transaction_entry e
left join billing.transaction t on e.transaction_id = t.id
where e.amount > '0' and t.created_at > '2019-06-30' and t.created_at <  
'2019-08-01' and t.type='MONTHLY_RENT'
group by left(t.reference_id,5)
order by t_amount desc;`
```

Comment: I believe you're looking for `count(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'active')`.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!